# manage similar structs, one with arrays, the other with pointers

Tags: c, x-macros

I have some structs containing arrays

```
struct mystruct_withArrays {
  int foo;
  int bar[MaxN];
  int baz[MaxM];
}
```

and their equivalent with pointers

```
struct mystruct_withPointers {
   int foo;
   int *bar;
   int *baz;
}
```

and **I want to avoid the double definition**. This is I want to make something as a template

```
#define myStruct(M,N)
...
```

such that `myStruct(MaxM,MaxN)` produces the array struct and `myStruct(,)` produces the struct with pointers.

Moreover, of course I want to do the same technique for multiple structs and to have automatic mapping from arrays to pointers. A final use case could be as follow

```
#include "mystructs.h"

//globals, for huge space usage

struct myStructA(1000,10000) hugeA;

struct myStructB(1024*1024) * hugeB;

void main(){


struct myStructA(,) smallA;
struct myStructB() smallB;


mapStruct(hugeA,smallA) //this is a macro
mapStruct(hugeB,smallB) //this is a macro

doSomething(smallA);
doSomethingMore(smallA,smallB);
doSomethingDetailed(smallB.qux);
}
```

where `mapStruct(hugeA, smallA)` is the obvious mapping `smallA.bar = hugeA.bar`, etc. The expanded code would be:

```
struct myStructA(1000,10000) hugeA;
struct myStructB(1024*1024) hugeB;

struct mystructA_withArrays {
  int foo;
  int bar[1000];
  int baz[10000];
} hugeA;

struct mystructB_withArrays * {
  int qux[1048576];
  int quux[1048576];
} hugeB;


void main(){


struct mystructA_withPointers {
  int foo;
  int * bar;
  int * baz;
} smallA;

struct mystructB_withArrays {
  int * qux;
  int * quxx;
} smallB;

smallA.bar=hugeA.bar;
smallA.baz=hugeA.baz;
smallB.qux=hugeB.qux;
smallB.quxx=hugeB.quxx;

doSomething(smallA);
doSomethingMore(smallA,smallB);
doSomethingDetailed(smallB.qux);

}
```

As you can see, the general idea is that some variables are allocated outside of the stack, but still without using malloc, just declaring them as globals. Even in some use case they are external globals from a linked shared object.

EDIT:
about memory performance, it is not easy to ascertain if malloc structs are better or worse than global struct. It depends also on the flag -mcmodel of the compiler

Comment: Re “same trick”: Programming should not be done by “tricks.” Since the choice is indicated in the macro invocation (`myStruct(MaxM,MaxN)` versus `myStruct(,)`), change it to be non-tricky: `myStructArrays(MaxM, MaxN)` versus `MyStructPointers` and just define two macros.

Comment: If [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil)'s simple solution does not work for your real use case, show an example of the multiple structures you want to declare later. Maybe you can implement this by passing a macro name as an argument to a different macro or by using an [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

Comment: Eric, I fail to see how two macros avoid the double definition of the entries foo bar baz

Comment: @arivero In addition to showing how you imagine the macro calls, please show the resulting structures and C code you want to get.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica :-D yep, or typecast again to (int *)

Comment: @Bodo expanded as suggested

Comment: No need to get rid of the `;` after `mapStruct(hugeA,smallA)`.

Comment: What is `#import` in `#import "mystructs.h"`?

Comment: @arivero I modified the macros in my answer to implement the assignments `smallA.bar=hugeA.bar;` etc.

Comment: `data heap without using malloc, just declaring them as globals`. They are not defined in the heap only in the static storage area which in many implementations is called `.bss` and `.data`. It does not have anything in common with the heap. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: @0___________ corrected, I was not sure if they were to be in .data or where, only know that I can store bigger structures than if I declare them inside a function (and thus in the stack). Sorry I assumed that whatever is not stack, is heap.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that is my question :-D  What should I put in mystructs.h so that the preprocessor produces the desired code?

Comment: @arivero structs with pointers to other global struct members - it makes no sense unless you follow this tutorial: https://github.com/Droogans/unmaintainable-code As a bonus you will get worse performance and memory footprint.

Comment: @0___________ I will be sincerely grateful if you can substantiate the argument that global structs will have worse performance than malloc structs and than stack-stored structs. Albeit the later are discarded because of size.

Comment: @arivero `#import` is not a valid preprocessor command - so code `#import "mystructs.h"` is unclear.   Are you compiling the code fragments you  posted here?    What compiler are you using?

Comment: Why not always create the pointer struct but optionally have the pointers set to allocated arrays upon initialization? Sounds like it would solve all the problems without creating a lot of obscure complexity. This really sounds like an "XY problem".

Comment: Would you mind to explain why the pointer structures are needed at all? It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @thebusybee (and Lundin). At some moment deeper in the code there are functions which are independent of the allocated size of the arrays, so they receive pointer structures. The question is, more, why the arrays. Mostly it is to avoid the malloc/free and because it was believed, at design, that it offered better memory performance (but note that O___ argues it doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to create several similar structures might be the use of an [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).
(Unlike the Wikipedia page, I pass the macro `X` as an argument instead of redefining the macro.)

I edited the code a bit to add the assignments of the arrays to the corresponding pointers. I used variadic macros to allow omitting the variable names in the argument list. This is to show the concept, there may be room for improvement.

Example file `macro.c`

```
#define LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_1(X, ...) \
    X(int, bar, MaxN, __VA_ARGS__) \
    X(int, baz, MaxM, __VA_ARGS__)

#define LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_2(X, ...) \
    X(char, bla1, MaxK, __VA_ARGS__) \
    X(char, bla2, MaxL, __VA_ARGS__)

#define CREATE_ARRAY_FIELD(type, name, size, ...) \
    type name[size];

#define CREATE_POINTER_FIELD(type, name, size, ...) \
    type *name;

struct mystruct_withArrays {
    int foo;
    LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_1(CREATE_ARRAY_FIELD)
}

struct mystruct_withPointers {
    int foo;
    LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_1(CREATE_POINTER_FIELD)
}

struct otherstruct_withArrays {
    int foo;
    LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_2(CREATE_ARRAY_FIELD)
}

struct otherstruct_withPointers {
    int foo;
    LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_2(CREATE_POINTER_FIELD)
}

mystruct_withArrays hugeA;
mystruct_withPointers smallA;

otherstruct_withArrays hugeB;
otherstruct_withPointers smallB;

#define ASSIGN_POINTERS(type, name, size, dest, src) \
    dest.name = src.name;

LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_1(ASSIGN_POINTERS, smallA, hugeA)

LIST_OF_ARRAY_FIELDS_2(ASSIGN_POINTERS, smallB, hugeB)
```

Result:

```
$ gcc -E macro.c
# 1 "macro.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "macro.c"
# 15 "macro.c"
struct mystruct_withArrays {
    int foo;
    int bar[MaxN]; int baz[MaxM];
}

struct mystruct_withPointers {
    int foo;
    int *bar; int *baz;
}

struct otherstruct_withArrays {
    int foo;
    char bla1[MaxK]; char bla2[MaxL];
}

struct otherstruct_withPointers {
    int foo;
    char *bla1; char *bla2;
}

mystruct_withArrays hugeA;
mystruct_withPointers smallA;

otherstruct_withArrays hugeB;
otherstruct_withPointers smallB;




smallA.bar = hugeA.bar; smallA.baz = hugeA.baz;

smallB.bla1 = hugeB.bla1; smallB.bla2 = hugeB.bla2;
```

Comment: This X Macro technique looks nice, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The sensible [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) solution seems to be this:

```
struct mystruct {
   int foo;
   int *bar;
   int *baz;
};

struct mystruct array = 
{ 
  .bar = (int[ 1000]){0},
  .baz = (int[10000]){0},
};

struct mystruct pointers;
```

Now the interface of this struct is the same no matter how data was allocated and "array structs" are 100% compatible with "pointer structs". If declared at file scope, the allocation of the compound literals will end up in `.bss`, same deal as in your pseudo code.

Comment: And I guess I could still combine with the X Macro to avoid duplication of bar baz ...

Comment: Another advantage of this approach is that it doesnt define the "huge" type, so there is not possibility of a mistake passing it as function parameter.

Comment: or   `.bar = malloc(100 * sizeof(*array.bar)),
  .baz = malloc(100000 * sizeof(*array.baz)),`

Comment: @0___________ In that case the struct needs to be declared at local scope.

Comment: @Lundin same as in the question. Pointer struct is defined in the function scope.

Comment: I am accepting Bodo answer because it is more in the line of the question (manage redundancy), while I agree that this other proposal makes a better structure than my own. Surely my final code will combine both. Thanks.